# DDD or old fashion?

Tags: asp.net, oop, domain-driven-design

We are about to design a site for rentacar reservations using asp.net. There is a change that the application will scale up and I was wondering what if using DDD would help in maintenance and performance. I was wondering on what if there are new similar sites designed using datasets and SPs or DDD. So my friends to DDD or go old fashion ?

Comment: Who says you can't do both?  DDD is about the design of the business logic, i.e. the /domain/.  No matter how you design the business logic, Datasets and SPs shouldn't factor into that.

Comment: usually ddd is on top of a O/R mapping tool. sure we can do both but i am sure that a mature o/r mapper like nhibernate will do the job better than our custom mapper will do. Isn't that right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you, I'm in the process of creating a new project and I chose the DDD way which I'm sure is better then the "old fashion" way (decoupled and better testability)... But I have to admit that I'm struggling with some questions and can't always find the answers... even on stackoverflow.com

For example, the concept of *aggregate root* vs the design of an ASP.NET MVC website (master/detail relations - creating/updating) ; Model binding vs complex object graphs including entity objects and value objects, etc. All these are *recent* concepts and even the *gurus* (like Eric Evans for DDD) don't know all the answers.

Finally, I think that community projects [S#arp Architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) are a very good place for learning, and [asking questions](http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture).

Comment: MVC pattern is about presentation. It should be decoupled from domain model. If You are validating http-posted string if it's in correct datetime format in your domain model, you are doing it wrong. If You are adding paging related stuff into your domain model, that's wrong too.

Comment: Normally you bind in model->view_model direction only (Automapper is a great tool for that). Sometimes you don't need view models at all (if domain object is flat and dumb data bag by nature).

Comment: If you are binding in view model->domain model direction, you drive design towards procedural code which is bad unless problems you are trying to solve are extra easy (then procedural code is shorter and more easily to comprehend). Whole point of object orientation is to decrease complexity by delegating responsibility to objects "underneath". So - instead You should call methods on your domain objects, passing according arguments.

Answer (score 2):

*"wondering what if using DDD would help in maintenance and performance."*

A bunch of things can help with that. TDD/BDD, IoC, a good OR/M like NHibernate (w/FluentNHibernate for configuration)...

DDD, done right, is just one pillar in creating clean, simple and maintainable software. But it's only one piece of the puzzle. DDD can go horribly wrong if you just create a bunch of anemic domain objects with manager classes, use stored procedures for data access and forget about dependency injection...

But done right, what DDD can give you is clean and clear code: the procedural spaghetti code of the old west will go away and you'll find it easier to move around your own code base. Refactoring can take place (and becomes way less scary).

Personally - I would never touch another "old school" code base, and I certainly wouldn't start a new project that way. Give me a greenfield project and I'm going to ask for ReSharper, NHibernate, FluentNHibernate and StructureMap. And that's all I'll need....

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to build sites that also perform well with DDD. The goal with DDD will be to let the domain be your driving model. Currently in our project we have used NHibernate as the Object Relational Mapper ontop of the domain. That is working very well, especially because NHibernate also supports different things to enhance performance like second-level cache. Lists of objects that need to be loaded from the database for 10000+ users only need one query and the different sessions will share the same memcache. So if you go with an ORM, make sure you make use of those cache-advantages!

What you should also consider is that for every release-cycle of your software you not only update the software (domain model) but also need to take care of updating the database when your domain model changes. However this is not different from having to update StoredProcs.

BTW: even when using DDD and an ORM, there will still be problems for which you might prefer to use SPs. Example: creating a new ordernumber. If 10000+ users are on your website and multilpe users want to create a new order, you have to make sure all ordernumbers stay unique. We found that we preferred SPs to do those kind of locking stuff above ORM.

If you now have the chance to try DDD definately have a go at it. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, DDD is good for large websites that are built with ASP.NET MVC.  However I caution that the ASP.NET MVC platform is still relatively immature at this time.  If you choose to use DDD then I suggest you consider ASP.NET MVC, TDD and the Repository Pattern as your technology mix.  If you're using standard WebForm I wouldn't suggest DDD.  If you're using SPs then DDD really isn't great as you can't use the Repository pattern since it relies on GetAll, GetByID, Insert, Update, Delete ... and you extend these out with Filters implemented in LINQ using IQueryable ... well if you are using SPs then you have to cancel out the whole advantage of this structure.  Just my view.

Comment: Actually i have little experience with nhibernate and its working great for me. I just wanna hear some thoughts on designing a new project that is expected to stand in time, will have good performance, scalability and will be easy on maintain. So I agree with Nissan Fan but I wanna share more thoughts on modern design.

Comment: I think NHibernate is a very mature solution, however I've become extremely happy with the Entity Framework in conjunction with the Repository Pattern.  This along with MVC, TDD is the pinacle of modern architecture on the .NET platform.